# Math and Java - find an available index from a scale value

Tags: java, math

Again, apologies for the poor title - very hard to describe.

I used the Java tag since that's the language I'm using for this project, but this is really applicable to any language.

I'll use a simplified example in an effort toward clarity.

Let's say I'm displaying a graphic that can be "zoomed", and I can access to a float between 0 and 1 that represents the scale.

Now let's say that there are different versions of this same graphic, the more "close-up" ones show a finer level of detail, while the versions that are farther away clearly show only important features.

Each of these versions is one-half the size of the next larger version.  The most close-up would be equivalent to zoom level of 1.

There might be any number of versions, each representing a view one-half as large as the last.

So when the user zooms the graphic, I need to check to see if they've reached a point where it'd be better to display a different version.  If they haven't reached that point, I'd just show a scaled (down) version of the previous level.

For example, say there are 5 different versions (although there could be any number), in an array, from smallest to largest (although I could reverse this if it was easier), so versions[4] is the largest and versions[0] is the smallest.

E.g.,

- at zoom of 1, show versions[4]
- at zoom of 0.5, show versions[3]
- at 0.25, show versions[2]
- at 0.125, show versions[1]
- at 0.0625, show versions[0]

Since there's no version available for half of versions[0], I'd still show versions[0] but at half size.  If there were another version added, it'd show when the overall scale (zoom) was 0.03125 or less.

For scales between, I should show the next largest image, but at a reduced size.

E.g.,

- At a zoom of 1, I'd show the largest (versions[4]), unscaled.
- At a zoom of 0.8, still show the largest but at 0.8 scale
- At a zoom of 0.5, show versions[3] unscaled
- At a zoom of 0.3, show versions[3] at 0.6 scale
- At a zoom of 0.2, show versions[2] at 0.8 scale
- At a zoom of 0.1, show versions[1] at 0.8 scale

I could probably hack this together with conditionals, or linking  and Math.abs, etc, but I'd bet there's a very elegant, efficient way to handle this with pure math - it's just way over my head.  If not, any suggestions as to an approach using clean, predictable code would be welcome as well.

To restate - the goal is to find the version (array index) of the version to show, as well as the relative scale it should be displayed at, based entirely on a "global" scale.

TYIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int indexToUse = 0-Math.round(Math.log(zoom)/Math.log(2));
double zoomToUse = zoom/Math.pow(2, -indexToUse);
```

This uses the information that each image is exactly 2x as large as the previous one.  That's an exponential scale, so its inverse, the log, is used to find the index to use.

After that, you take 2 to the power of the index to get the zoom level it's actually at, and divide the desired zoom level by the actual to get your factor.

(Since you're working with zoom that's always between 0 and 1, the log will always be negative, so I went ahead and negated it.  Reordering your images to fit this might be easier, or you might just want to subtract from the length to get your actual index to use.)

BigMoMo pointed out that Java's Math.log is the natural log.  Also, as he pointed out, you can get log2 by dividing the natural log by the natural log of 2.  I've reflected this in the sample code.

To address your secondary question,

```
double getZoom(int index, double zoomOnImage){
    return Math.pow(2, -index) * zoomOnImage;
}
```

Comment: @bdares thanks for the reply - excuse me if i'm making a simple mistake, but Math.log only accepts a single argument, right?

Comment: @bdares - would it be Math.log(zoom) / Math.log(2) ?

Comment: @BigMoMo you're right.. I was too lazy to check the API and just pounded out some code that looked about right, but probably wouldn't compile, as with the negated `indexToUse` in the second line.

Comment: @bdares yep - i just ran it and it works great - like you said, it runs opposite (smallest to largest), but that's no problem - like John said, very impressive, especially in the 11 minutes from the time of posting.  thanks very much

Comment: @bdares hope i'm not pushing my luck here, but do you know how to go backwards (from an index and scale to a zoom)?  i can open another question if you'd like

Answer (score 0):

If you try an interface such as [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com), you'll notice that it *doesn't* scale continuously. Instead it moves in steps.

So one approach is to only permit the user to zoom stepwise, and map these steps directly to your graphics versions at various real scales. You could still show each set of tiles at different scales, e.g.

```
  Zoom  Tileset  Scale
   1       1       0.5
   2       1       1
   3       2       0.25
   4       2       0.5
   5       2       1
   ...
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this i have to offer smooth interpolation between states - the primary mode of user-scale is via pinch gesture

Answer (score 0):

If reverse the order like:

at zoom of 1, show versions[0] (the largest); at zoom of 0.5, show versions[1]; at 0.25, show versions[2]; at 0.125, show versions[3]; at 0.0625, show versions[4]; ...

We can see clearly that the index **i = log(zoom)/log(0.5)**;  or **zoom=pow(0.5, i).**
For those cases when zoom is not exactly power of 0.5, we just take the ceil or integar part, e.g. when zoom=0.4, log(0.4)/log(0.5)=1.32192, then index should be 1. So, to be simple index is the integar part of log(zoom)/log(0.5).

The actually zoom is: zoom/z[i] (i is the index, z is the zoom array {1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625} )

Continue above example, for given zoom 0.4, index = 1 (from above), and final zoom is: 0.4/z[i] = 0.4/z[1] = 0.4/0.5 = 0.8.

In order to get index in practice/implementation, you don't need to calculate log(x), just compare the zoom value to see which slot/index it fits in (using sort of binary search strategy). Once index is found, final zoom is calculated by zoom/z[i].

Comment: thanks for the response.  do you see any advantage in use the approach you've mentioned, as opposed to the pure math solution?

Comment: first I just explained it in math way. I know the math way and I did not oppose it:-) I mean in order to get index of the array, don't need 'log' kind of math method if we implement it especially if there are many levels of zooms. Searching its position (comparing) should be more efficient then "log" operation on float.